# SQL bulk updates not working

Tags: c#, sql, .net

This is my first attempt at using a `SqlAdapter` to perform a batch update to a SQL. I'm trying to follow the demo [on this page](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0560__ADO.Net/BatchUpdateDemo.htm) however the line `adapter.Fill(ds, "ZipCodeTerritory");` keeps giving me the error

`Must declare the scalar variable \"@ChannelCode\"`

I'm trying to load the contents of a `List` into a `DataSet` object and then use the `.Update()` method on the `SqlAdapter` to perform a batch update (around 14k records).

```
    private static string updateCommand = "UPDATE ZipCodeTerritory SET ChannelCode = @ChannelCode, DrmTerrDesc = @DrmTerrDesc, IndDistrnId = @IndDistrnId," +
                                                "StateCode = @StateCode, ZipCode = @ZipCode, EndDate = @EndDate, EffectiveDate = @EffectiveDate," +
                                                "LastUpdateId = @LastUpdateId, LastUpdateDate = @LastUpdateDate, ErrorCodes = @ErrorCodes," + 
                                                "Status = @Status " +
                                          "WHERE Id = @Id";

    public static void Update(List<ZipCodeTerritory> updates, Dictionary<ZipCodeTerritory, string> errorList)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(updateCommand, connection))
            {
                try
                {
                    DataTable dataTable = LoadData(updates);

                    SqlCommand updateCmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                    updateCmd.CommandText = updateCommand;
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ChannelCode", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "ChannelCode"));
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DrmTerrDesc", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "DrmTerrDesc"));
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IndDistrnId", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "IndistrnId"));
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StateCode", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "StateCode"));
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ZipCode", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "ZipCode"));
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EndDate", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "EndDate"));
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EffectiveDate", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "EffectiveDate"));
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastUpdateId", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "LastUpdateId"));
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastUpdateDate", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "LastUpdateDate"));
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "Id"));
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ErrorCodes", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "ErrorCodes"));
                    updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Status", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "Status"));
                    updateCmd.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;

                    adapter.UpdateCommand = updateCmd;
                    adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;

                    DataSet ds = LoadDataSet(updates);

                    adapter.Fill(ds, "ZipCodeTerritory");

                    connection.Open();

                    adapter.Update(ds, "ZipCodeTerritory");

                    connection.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string msg = ex.Message;
                }                    
            }
        }
    }

    private static DataSet LoadDataSet(List<ZipCodeTerritory> zipcodeList)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        DataTable data = LoadData(zipcodeList);

        ds.Tables.Add(data);

        return ds;
    }

    private static DataTable LoadData(List<ZipCodeTerritory>zipCodeList)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = InitializeStructure();

        foreach (var zipcode in zipCodeList)
        {
            DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();

            try
            {
                row[0] = zipcode.ChannelCode.Trim();
                row[1] = zipcode.DrmTerrDesc.Trim();
                row[2] = zipcode.IndDistrnId.Trim();
                row[3] = zipcode.StateCode.Trim();
                row[4] = zipcode.ZipCode.Trim();
                row[5] = zipcode.EndDate.Date;
                row[6] = zipcode.EffectiveDate.Date;
                row[7] = zipcode.LastUpdateId;
                row[8] = DateTime.Now.Date;
                row[10] = zipcode.ErrorCodes;
                row[11] = zipcode.Status;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return dataTable;
    }

    private static DataTable InitializeStructure()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("ChannelCode", typeof (string));
        dt.Columns.Add("DrmTerrDesc", typeof (string));
        dt.Columns.Add("IndDistrnId", typeof (string));
        dt.Columns.Add("StateCode", typeof (string));
        dt.Columns.Add("ZipCode", typeof (string));
        dt.Columns.Add("EndDate", typeof (DateTime));
        dt.Columns.Add("EffectiveDate", typeof (DateTime));
        dt.Columns.Add("LastUpdateId", typeof (string));
        dt.Columns.Add("LastUpdateDate", typeof (DateTime));
        dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof (int));
        dt.Columns.Add("ErrorCodes", typeof (string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Status", typeof (string));

        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: You haven't defined a `SelectCommand` for the `adapter` (you're using the `updateCommand` in the constructor). Try creating the command and then using `adapter.Fill`.

Comment: @Romoku - (just curious) why do they need you to create the `SelectCommand` if you're only using the update?

Comment: If you're calling `DataAdapter.Fill` it is going to dump the result of the `SelectCommand` property into the `DataSet`. Omit those lines if you don't want this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line here:

```
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(updateCommand, connection))
```

The SqlDataAdapter constructor needs a *Select* command, an Update command will not work.  When you try to execute the `Fill` method it fails because it has no `.SelectCommand` parameters to apply.