# Use SqlAdapter and DataSet to perform bulk updates to SQL table

Tags: c#, sql, .net, batch-updates

Below is the code I'm using to bulk update (about 14k records) our `ZipCodeTerritory` table. The code runs fine, without any exceptions, however when I check the table after the `connection` is closed I see that none of the changes have been made.

I am holding all the records that need to be updated in the `List` object I pass between methods. I use this `List` to fill the `DataTable` and place that into a `DataSet` to perform the update.

This is my first attempt trying to use this technique so any suggestions greatly appreciated.

```
private static string selectCommand =
   "SELECT ChannelCode, DrmTerrDesc, IndDistrnId, StateCode, ZipCode, EndDate, 
     EffectiveDate, LastUpdateId, LastUpdateDate, Id, ErrorCodes, Status FROM
     ZipCodeTerritory";

private static string updateCommand = "UPDATE ZipCodeTerritory SET ChannelCode =
                                      @ChannelCode, DrmTerrDesc = @DrmTerrDesc,
                                      IndDistrnId = @IndDistrnId," + 
                                      "StateCode = @StateCode, ZipCode = @ZipCode,
                                      EndDate = @EndDate, EffectiveDate = 
                                      @EffectiveDate," + 
                                      "LastUpdateId = @LastUpdateId, LastUpdateDate
                                      = @LastUpdateDate, ErrorCodes = @ErrorCodes,"
                                      + "Status = @Status " + 
                                      "WHERE Id = @Id";

public static void Update(List<ZipCodeTerritory> updates, Dictionary<ZipCodeTerritory, string> errorList)
{
   using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
   {
      using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, connection))
      {
         try
         {
            SqlCommand updateCmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            updateCmd.CommandText = updateCommand;
            updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ChannelCode", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "ChannelCode"));
            updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DrmTerrDesc", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "DrmTerrDesc"));
            updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IndDistrnId", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "IndistrnId"));
            updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StateCode", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "StateCode"));
            updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ZipCode", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "ZipCode"));
            updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EndDate", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "EndDate"));
            updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EffectiveDate", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "EffectiveDate"));
            updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastUpdateId", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "LastUpdateId"));
            updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastUpdateDate", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "LastUpdateDate"));
            updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "Id"));
            updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ErrorCodes", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "ErrorCodes"));
            updateCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Status", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "Status"));
            updateCmd.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.None;
            adapter.UpdateCommand = updateCmd;
            adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
            DataSet ds = LoadDataSet(updates);
            connection.Open();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "ZipCodeTerritory");
            adapter.Update(ds, "ZipCodeTerritory");
            connection.Close();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            string msg = ex.Message;
         }                    
      }
   }
}

private static DataSet LoadDataSet(List<ZipCodeTerritory> zipcodeList)
{
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   DataTable data = LoadData(zipcodeList);
   ds.Tables.Add(data);
   return ds;
}

private static DataTable LoadData(List<ZipCodeTerritory>zipCodeList)
{
   DataTable dataTable = InitializeStructure();

   foreach (var zipcode in zipCodeList)
   {
      DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();

      try
      {
         row[0] = zipcode.ChannelCode.Trim();
         row[1] = zipcode.DrmTerrDesc.Trim();
         row[2] = zipcode.IndDistrnId.Trim();
         row[3] = zipcode.StateCode.Trim();
         row[4] = zipcode.ZipCode.Trim();
         row[5] = zipcode.EndDate.Date;
         row[6] = zipcode.EffectiveDate.Date;
         row[7] = zipcode.LastUpdateId;
         row[8] = DateTime.Now.Date;
         //row[9] = zipcode.Id;
         row[10] = zipcode.ErrorCodes;
         row[11] = zipcode.Status;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {

      }
      dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
   }
   return dataTable;
}

private static DataTable InitializeStructure()
{
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();

   dt.Columns.Add("ChannelCode", typeof (string));
   dt.Columns.Add("DrmTerrDesc", typeof (string));
   dt.Columns.Add("IndDistrnId", typeof (string));
   dt.Columns.Add("StateCode", typeof (string));
   dt.Columns.Add("ZipCode", typeof (string));
   dt.Columns.Add("EndDate", typeof (DateTime));
   dt.Columns.Add("EffectiveDate", typeof (DateTime));
   dt.Columns.Add("LastUpdateId", typeof (string));
   dt.Columns.Add("LastUpdateDate", typeof (DateTime));
   dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof (int));
   dt.Columns.Add("ErrorCodes", typeof (string));
   dt.Columns.Add("Status", typeof (string));
   return dt;
}
```

**EDIT**

I've changed the order for the `.Fill` and `LoadDataSet()` methods to first load the data from the database as it currently sits and THEN merge the changes into that `DataSet`. However, I'm now getting the following error:

```
`Update unable to find TableMapping['ZipCodeTerritory'] or DataTable 'ZipCodeTerritory'`
```

I realized I hadn't named the table so I changed the `InitializeStructure()` method to the following

```
    private static DataTable InitializeStructure()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("ZipCodeTerritory");
```

However.... now when I attempt the `.Update` on this line

```
 adapter.Update(ds, "ZipCodeTerritory");
```

I get this exception:

```
Update requires a valid InsertCommand when passed DataRow collection with new rows.
```

**SECOND EDIT**

I've added the following `InsertCommand` to the `Update` method (this is the first few lines of code inside the `try` that contains the `updateCommand`):

```
    SqlCommand insertCmd = new SqlCommand(insertCommand, connection);
    insertCmd.CommandText = updateCommand;
    insertCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ChannelCode", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "ChannelCode"));
    insertCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DrmTerrDesc", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30, "DrmTerrDesc"));
    insertCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@IndDistrnId", SqlDbType.Char, 3, "IndDistrnId"));
    insertCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StateCode", SqlDbType.Char, 3, "StateCode"));
    insertCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ZipCode", SqlDbType.Char, 9, "ZipCode"));
    insertCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EndDate", SqlDbType.Date, 10, "EndDate"));
    insertCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EffectiveDate", SqlDbType.Date, 10, "EffectiveDate"));
    insertCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastUpdateId", SqlDbType.Char, 8, "LastUpdateId"));
    insertCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastUpdateDate", SqlDbType.Date, 10, "LastUpdateDate"));
    insertCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, 20, "Id"));
    insertCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ErrorCodes", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255, "ErrorCodes"));
    insertCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Status", SqlDbType.Char, 1, "Status"));

    adapter.InsertCommand = insertCmd;
```

However I am still not seeing any changes in the database.

Comment: A commit? did I miss it?

Comment: Your code: 1) populates datatable from the list; 2) then populates it from the database, probably, merging rows data by primary key, thus your data table becomes the same as your database table; 3) then updates database, but, since the data in the data table looks like data in database, nothing happens. At least, you need to swap `adapter.Fill` with `LoadDataSet`, and rewrite `LoadDataSet` to modify records, loaded from database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL bulk updates not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21144591/sql-bulk-updates-not-working)

Comment: Same title but different problem. Other question an issue with the `.Fill` statement. This is past that problem and the database not being updated.

Comment: @Dennis - the records the list holds are already updated. I'm importing from a spreadsheet and I'd like to take all the records in the list and update all non-PK fields where the PK is a match. Am i using the right technique?

Comment: Regarding your last update you just need to set correct InsertCommand on adapter. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.insertcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Vitaliy I dont have any new records to insert. I exported 14k records into an Excel spreadsheet, made a change to each record, and now want to use that spreadsheet to update those records. Do I still need to use an Insert command?